# Can't determine issue with JS storeClient function and error thrown

Tags: javascript, zapier

I have created two async functions within my JavaScript Zapier step to parse  a raw webhook.  The two async functions center around storeClient to "get" and "set" values on Storage by Zapier.  However, I get an error thrown.  I have a screen shot from Zapier test sub-step.  Due to the way Zapier returns on error, I can't see any of my console.log output.

What have I done wrong with the async functions?

```
    // function to talk to Storage By Zapier to get a key
    //
    async function getStore(passKey) {
        try {
            const store = StoreClient(inputData.secret);
            const data = await store.get(passKey);
            console.log(`Here is the data from store: ${data}`);
            return data;
         } catch(error) {
            console.log(`We hit an error: ${error}`);
         }
     }

     // function to talk to Storage By Zapier to set a key and values
     //
     async function setStore(passKey, passTags) {
         try {
             const store = StoreClient(inputData.secret);
             await store.setMany({'email': passKey, 'tags': passTags});
         } catch(error) {
             console.log(`We hit an error: ${error}`);
         }
     }

     // for testing in editor
     //
     //var contactData = JSON.parse(raw);
     // only when Storage By Zapier not available 
     //var inputData  = JSON.parse(inputStore);

     // pull in data from Zapier
     //
     var contactData = JSON.parse(inputData.raw);
     //console.log(contactData);
     //console.log(inputData.secret);
     //var inputData = JSON.parse(inputData.testStore);
     //console.log(inputData.tags);
     //console.log(`inputData.tags: ${inputData.tags}`);

     //
     //  create output object to pass back to zapier after processing webhook from AgileCRM
     //
     //  receive raw webhook by parsing using built-in function
     //
     var output = new Object();

     //console.log(`inputData.tags: ${inputData.tags}`);

     var contactEventData, isValentus, isDoubleOptIn, isUpdate, contactTags, tagsDidntchange, storeTags, storeTagsArray, tagsEqualCount;

     // set-up variables and init
     //
     isValentus       = false;
     isDoubleOptIn    = false;
     tagsDidntchange  = false;
     contactTags      = new Array();
     storeTagsArray   = new Array();
     tagsEqualCount   = 0;
     contactEventData = contactData.eventData;

     //  find out is this is an update to a contact
     //
     contactData.eventName === 'Contact is Updated' ? isUpdate = true : isUpdate = false;

     //  find out if the contact is:
     //      Valentus, Double Opt-in and save other tags
     //
     contactEventData.tags.forEach(function(contactTag) {
         switch(contactTag) {
             case 'Valentus':
                 isValentus = true;
                 break;
             case 'Double_Opt_In':
                 isDoubleOptIn = true;
                 break;
             default:
                 contactTags.push(contactTag);
         }
     })

     //  initialize all variables to be passed via output object to Zapier
     //     ---this is so that the subsequent steps in the zap have data for the variable
     //
     var contactEmailAddress = '-', contactFirstName ='-', contactLastName = '-', contactPhoneNumber = '-', contactSource = '-', contactValentusUSERID = '-', contactStatus = '-', contactPhoneCallType = '-', contactInvitedby = '-', contactInvitedByEmail = '-', contactInvitedByWebsiteUID = '-', contactInvitedByValentusUSERID = '-', contactValentusTeam = '-';

     //  process contact properties to get needed variable data by property name
     //
     contactEventData.properties.forEach(function(properties) {
         let propertyName  = properties.name;
         let propertyValue = properties.value;
         switch(propertyName) {
             case 'email':
                 contactEmailAddress = propertyValue;
                 break;
             case 'first_name':
                 contactFirstName = propertyValue;
                 break;
             case 'last_name':
                 contactLastName = propertyValue;
                 break;
             case 'phone':
                 contactPhoneNumber = propertyValue;
                 break;
             case 'Source':
                 contactSource = propertyValue;
                 break;
             case 'Valentus userid': 
                 contactValentusUSERID = propertyValue;
                 break;
             case 'Status':
                 contactStatus = propertyValue;
                 break;
             case 'Phone call type':
                 contactPhoneCallType = propertyValue;
                 break;
             case 'Invited by':
                 contactInvitedby = propertyValue;
                 break;
             case 'Invited by email':
                 contactInvitedByEmail = propertyValue;
                 break;
             case 'Invited by website UID':
                 contactInvitedByWebsiteUID = propertyValue;
                 break;
             case 'Invited by Valentus userid':
                 contactInvitedByValentusUSERID = propertyValue;
                 break;
             case 'company':
                 contactValentusTeam = propertyValue;
                 break;
         }
     })

     //  get storage by email address and compare tags
     //  and see if tags changed.  if they changed, we don't
     //  want to process any further
     //
     //storeTags = inputData.tags;

     getStore(contactEmailAddress).then(data => {
         console.log(data);
         storeTags = data;
     });
     //console.log(`storeTags returned is: ${storeTags}`);

     //  Transform store string into array of tags to compare 
     //  with hook tags array
     //
     storeTagsArray = storeTags.split(',');

     //  compare storeTags to contactTags
     //    --note both arrays may not be in same order
     //
     contactTags.forEach(function(contactTag) {
         storeTagsArray.forEach(function(storeTag) {
             if (storeTag === contactTag) {
                 tagsEqualCount++;
             }
         })
     })

     if (tagsEqualCount === storeTagsArray.length && tagsEqualCount === contactTags.length) {
         tagsDidntchange = true;
     } else {
         setStore(contactEmailAddress, contactTags);
     }

     //  now place contact property variables into output object to pass
     //
     output = {
         'isValentus': isValentus,
         'isUpdate': isUpdate,
         'isDoubleOptIn': isDoubleOptIn,
         'tagsDidntchange': tagsDidntchange,
         'contactEmailAddress': contactEmailAddress, 
         'contactFirstName': contactFirstName, 
         'contactLastName': contactLastName, 
         'contactPhoneNumber': contactPhoneNumber, 
         'contactSource': contactSource, 
         'contactValentusUSERID': contactValentusUSERID, 
         'contactStatus': contactStatus, 
         'contactPhoneCallType': contactPhoneCallType, 
         'contactInvitedby': contactInvitedby, 
         'contactInvitedByEmail': contactInvitedByEmail, 
         'contactInvitedByWebsiteUID': contactInvitedByWebsiteUID, 
         'contactInvitedByValentusUSERID': contactInvitedByValentusUSERID, 
         'contactValentusTeam': contactValentusTeam,
         'contactTags': contactTags
     };

     /*  for debug */
     console.log(output);
     /**/
```

[screen shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfHb9.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Try to be specific on what your question is and avoid asking more than 1 question at a time for your post to get attention else people will just fly away. No one likes to read more text.

Comment: this looks like an awesome use case! I think you're running into some async issues where your code is running out of order. namely, your `.then` doesn't finish before the rest runs. can you update your post with a screenshot of the error so I can confirm?

Comment: @xavdid, I figured it out.  See attached in post.

Comment: you did figure it out, or do you still need help? I believe I've spotted your error

Comment: No, I have not figured out the problem.  I'm sure as soon as you tell, it will be an oohhh shout moment.  THANKS

Comment: @xaxdid, the "I figured it out" comment was about figuring out how to add a screen shoot to the original question.  I still haven't figured out what my problem is.  You mentioned you believe you spotted the error.  Can you please elaborate?  Thanks.

Comment: @xavdid, sorry.  I typo'ed your userid from the last comment.

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

The root of your issue is on the following line:

```
 storeTagsArray = storeTags.split(',');
```

If `storeTagsArray` is `undefined`, then calling `.split()` on it crashes.

The reason it's undefined is the way you're handling async code above. Namely, this, directly above:

```
getStore(contactEmailAddress).then(data => { // line 1
     console.log(data);                      // line 2
     storeTags = data;                       // line 3
 });

storeTagsArray = storeTags.split(',');       // line 4
```

You're correct to use `.then` after the promise, but the code outside the `then` keeps running in the meantime. The order of execution above is line 1, 4, (eventually) 2, 3. Since 4 runs before `storeTagsArray` has been initialized, it's still `undefined`.

The solution here is easy - use `await`:

```
storeTags = await getStore(contactEmailAddress)
storeTagsArray = storeTags.split(',');
```

We wrap all your code in a big `async` function, so you should be able to await wherever you need it. There's a little more info [here](https://zapier.com/help/code/#introductory-http-example).

You've got another `.then` that you'll need to fix in a similar manner and then your code should run top-to-bottom, just as expected!

Comment: Thanks so much @xavdid.  I knew it had to be something simple that I overlooked. :).  I will try it out shortly.  Again, THANKS.